# how to configure delay between outgoing email in exim

Tags: exim

I'd like to ask how to configure delays for outgoing email in the exim level. If my users generate multiple emails at the same time, i want the server to send one by one, with 10 seconds in between.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - you can't. `exim` designed to send messages as fast as possible due to the absence of mailqueue. Immediately after submission `exim` try to deliver the message, and, if failed, store that message in the spool for later proceeding.

Exim have the rate-limit mechanism that limit the submission rate for specific user, but there is no native functionality that allow to relay messages with desired interval between them.

Comment: Thanks @Kondybas, no wonder i can't find such info in the internet

Answer (score 0):

"The simplest way to add SMTP transaction delays is to append a delay control to the final accept statement in each of the ACLs we have declared, as follows:"

```
accept
    delay = 20s
```

Taken from [here](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Spam-Filtering-for-MX/exim-smtpdelays.html).

Comment: Unfortunately that is for receiving only. Each incoming session will be delayed for N seconds before HELO will be sent. That was intended to kick off spamer's mass-mailers which do not want to wait and rather will drop the session than will wait for undefined period of time. And there is no such functionality for outgoing messages - for obvious reasons.